# SQL Query Optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I am trying to speed up this django app (note: I didn't design this... just stuck maintaining it) and the biggest bottle neck seems to be these queries that are being generated by the admin. We have a content class that 4-5 other sub-classes inherit from and anytime the master list is pulled up in the admin a query like this is generated:

```
SELECT `content_content`.`id`,
       `content_content`.`issue_id`,
       `content_content`.`slug`,
       `content_content`.`section_id`,
       `content_content`.`priority`,
       `content_content`.`group_id`,
       `content_content`.`rotatable`,
       `content_content`.`pub_status`,
       `content_content`.`created_on`,
       `content_content`.`modified_on`,
       `content_content`.`old_pk`,
       `content_content`.`content_type_id`,
       `content_image`.`content_ptr_id`,
       `content_image`.`caption`,
       `content_image`.`kicker`,
       `content_image`.`pic`,
       `content_image`.`crop_x`,
       `content_image`.`crop_y`,
       `content_image`.`crop_side`,
       `content_issue`.`id`,
       `content_issue`.`special_issue_name`,
       `content_issue`.`web_publish_date`,
       `content_issue`.`issue_date`,
       `content_issue`.`fm_name`,
       `content_issue`.`arts_name`,
       `content_issue`.`comments`,
       `content_section`.`id`,
       `content_section`.`name`,
       `content_section`.`audiodizer_id`
  FROM `content_image`
 INNER
  JOIN `content_content`
    ON `content_image`.`content_ptr_id` = `content_content`.`id`
 INNER
  JOIN `content_issue`
    ON `content_content`.`issue_id` = `content_issue`.`id`
 INNER
  JOIN `content_section`
    ON `content_content`.`section_id` = `content_section`.`id`
 WHERE NOT ( `content_content`.`pub_status` = -1 )
 ORDER BY `content_issue`.`issue_date` DESC LIMIT 30
```

I ran an EXPLAIN on this and got the following:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type   | possible_keys                                                                                   | key     | key_len | ref                                  | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | content_image   | ALL    | PRIMARY                                                                                         | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                 | 40499 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | content_content | eq_ref | PRIMARY,issue_id,content_content_issue_id,content_content_section_id,content_content_pub_status | PRIMARY | 4       | content_image.content_ptr_id         |     1 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | content_section | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                         | PRIMARY | 4       | content_content.section_id           |     1 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | content_issue   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                         | PRIMARY | 4       | content_content.issue_id             |     1 |                                 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
```

Now, from what I've read, I need to somehow figure out how to make the query to content_image not be terrible; however, I'm drawing a blank on where to start.

Comment: You select **everything** from `content_image` table (since you don't have any `WHERE` that filters out some rows) - so you have a table fullscan. What else do you expect to see?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, judging by the execution plan, MySQL is starting with `content_image`, retrieving *all* rows, and only thereafter using primary keys on the other tables: `content_image` has a foreign key to `content_content`, and `content_content` has foreign keys to `content_issue` and `content_section`. Also, only after all the joins are complete can it make much use of the `ORDER BY content_issue.issue_date DESC LIMIT 30`, since it can't tell which of these joins might fail, and therefore, how many records from `content_issue` will really be needed before it can get the first thirty rows of output.

So, I would try the following:

- Change `JOIN content_issue` to `JOIN (SELECT * FROM content_issue ORDER BY issue_date DESC LIMIT 30) content_issue`. This will allow MySQL, if it starts with `content_issue` and works its way to the other tables, to grab a very small subset of `content_issue`.

  - Note: properly speaking, this changes the semantics of the query: it means that only records from at most the last 30 `content_issue`s will be retrieved, and therefore that if some of those issues don't have published contents with images, then fewer than 30 records will be retrieved. I don't have enough information about your data to gauge whether this change of semantics would actually change the results you get.
  - Also note: I'm not suggesting to remove the `ORDER BY content_issue.issue_date DESC LIMIT 30` from the end of the query. I think you want it in both places.
- Add an index on `content_issue.issue_date`, to optimize the above subquery.
- Add an index on `content_image.content_ptr_id`, so MySQL can work its way from `content_content` to `content_image` without doing a full table scan.